# RenderPartial from different folder in RAZOR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I've been trying to convert my aspx pages to cshtml and having an issue with rendering partial pages from another folder.

What I used to do:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Inquiry/InquiryList.ascx", Model.InquiryList.OrderBy("InquiryId", MvcContrib.Sorting.SortDirection.Descending));%>
```

I would think that the equivalent would be:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Inquiry/_InquiryList.cshtml", Model.InquiryList.OrderBy("InquiryId", MvcContrib.Sorting.SortDirection.Descending))
```

This is obviously not working, I am getting the following error.

> CS1973:
>   'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper'
>   has no applicable method named
>   'Partial' but appears to have an
>   extension method by that name.
>   Extension methods cannot be
>   dynamically dispatched. Consider
>   casting the dynamic arguments or
>   calling the extension method without
>   the extension method syntax.

How would I achieve this with using the Razor view engine?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [RenderPartial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.renderpartialextensions.renderpartial(VS.98).aspx) does not return a string or IHtmlString value. But does the rendering by calling Write in the Response.

You could use the [Partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402926(v=VS.98).aspx) extension, this returns an MvcHtmlString

```
 @Html.Partial( ....
```

or

```
 @{ Html.RenderPartial(....);  }
```

If you really want RenderPartial

Comment: Writing to the response stream directly is considered more efficient though so you should still go for RenderPartial unless you need the partial as a string for editing or some other reason

Answer (score 7):

The compiler cannot choose the correct method because your Model is dynamic. Change the call to:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Inquiry/_InquiryList.cshtml", (List<string>)Model.InquiryList)
```

Or to whatever data type InquiryList is.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to include your strongly typed `@model` directive in your new Razor view. It is an easy step to miss when converting views from .aspx to .cshtml. If you forget, that *'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' has no applicable method named 'Partial'* error message could appear.